# How do I automatically run on an environment with Spyder?

Tags: python, environment, spyder

Sorry if I am unclear/this is a lame question, still very new to setting up my computer.

So I installed Python using Anaconda for work, and at work there are specific packages that are used internally. I used Anaconda Prompt to install these packages by creating an environment and installing internally used packages. I then check to see if the package is there.

In the Anaconda Prompt...

```
conda create --name environment_name python = 3.4
activate environment_name
pip install <internal package> --upgrade
pip list
```

However, when I try to import a package on Spyder, it does not recognize the package. Is there a way for Spyder to run code on an environment that I specify? I would like the environment to run automatically on any file that I run using Spyder, being able to pull the packages that I installed on Anaconda Prompt

Comment: How are you starting Spyder? Did you activate the environment before starting it? You might have to install Spyder into that environment as well: `activate environment_name` then `conda install spyder`

Comment: hmm I tried doing that, and I'm getting an error saying that it cannot connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/ ...is this a firewall issue? Strange because I could install packages in my environment using 'pip', though. Is there a directory where environments are stored that I can change my path within Spyder to run on? When I type in 'pip list' into the prompt, I see the spyder package inside

Comment: Did you activate your new environment before starting Spyder? Unfortunately, I'm not really sure about the connection issue...

Comment: Yes, I pull up Anaconda prompt, type in 'activate environment_name', and then I open up Spyder, and the packages cannot be imported. When I open up preferences > python console, the path is the Default PYTHONSTARTUP script. Should I be using a different one?